# FullCalendar Date Text Color Not Changing (Not Event Text)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using [fullcalendar](/questions/tagged/fullcalendar) (version 3.6.2) and have set `bootstrap3` as the `themeSystem`.  Upon user triggers some calculation, I would like to update the calendar.  A certain date would have new background colour (e.g. `DarkRed`) and the text colour (of the date) needs to be white to be visible.

This is what I did originally:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'dayRender', function (date, cell) {
    if (date.local().isSame(moment(newDate))) {
        cell.css("background-color", "DarkRed");
        cell.css("color", "white");
    }
});
```

`"newDate"` is the calculated date in Moment.

The background colour changed correctly. However, the text colour does not change to white.

Then I inspected the cell and realised that the date is on another div. It's displayed on `fc-content-skeleton`.

How do I change CSS `color` for this?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue through https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: oh, it's ok.. I've solved it via answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!  Thanks to a friend who gave some pointers.

As above, we already know the date of the cell to be changed.  We can already change `background-color`.  To get the correct `<td>` in the `fc-content-skeleton`, we find using `[data-date]` attribute.

`$('td').find("[data-date='" + newDateShort + "']")` will give the correct `<td>`, where `newDateShort` is the date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Hence, we change colour of it.

```
$('td').find("[data-date='" + newDateShort + "']").css("color", "white");
```